# Creating custom Hint window

Tags: delphi, hints

I'm trying to find a way to use my 2nd form as a hint window for a component (for example a TLabel) in my 1st form.

At the moment, I'm exploring the use of `THintWindow` and `HintWindowClass`, but it is not possible to directly assign a `TForm` to `HintWindowClass`. Some examples I've seen so far use a `TBitmap` which is then drawn on the `THintWindow.Canvas`, which is not bad, but I'd still like to use some kind of integrated automatic mechanism.

Another solution that crossed my mind is to manually implement this functionality using `OnMouseEnter`, `OnMouseMove` and `OnMouseLeave` events of the said Tlabel.

If there actually is a way to "assign" a `TForm` to `HintWindowClass`, I'd like to ask if anyone can provide a code snippet illustrating this. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`THintWindow` is a descendant of `TCustomControl`. `TForm` is not a descendant of either of those classes, so you cannot assign any `TForm` class to `HintWindowClass`. Hint windows need to descend from `THintWindow`. Anything you can put on a form you can also put on a `THintWindow`. You'll just have to instantiate it manually and assign its `Parent` property to make it appear.

The closest you can probably get to "visually" designing a hint window is to design a **frame**. Make your `THintWindow` descendant create an instance of the frame, and then override `ActivateHint` (and `ActivateHintData`, if you need the data) to forward the hint text and desired size to your frame.

Comment: It's a little bit hacky, but you could place the form you want to use as a hint inside a container derived from `THintWindow`. You would set `Form.Parent := HintWindowContainer; Form.Align := alClient;`

Comment: I'm not sure on the policy of "reviving" one year old questions here, but this is the exact question that I have right now. I understand what needs to be done, but I don't know how to exactly. I have made `TMyHintWindow` descendant and looked at `ActivateHint` and from there I'm lost, do I completely throw away the original code, where should I put the creation of an instance of a frame? I tried doing it in `ActivateHint`, it gets created but never shows up... then again, I didn't reuse any original code, so that's probably completely wrong. I would appreciate some help with this.